# Merge files in a directory using Linq to Objects

Tags: c#, linq, file, merge

I have  a set of txt files in a directory. I want to merge them all in to one with contects appended. How can this be achieved using Linq?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this in .Net 4 relatively easily:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    outputFileName,
    Directory.EnumerateFiles(inputDirectory, @"*.txt")
             .SelectMany(file => File.ReadLines(file)));
```

You could extract this into a method:

```
public static void ConcatenateFiles(
    string outputFileName, IEnumerable<string> inputFiles)
{
    File.WriteAllLines(outputFileName, inputFiles.SelectMany(File.ReadLines));
}
```

Called like so:

```
ConcatenateFiles("test.out", Directory.EnumerateFiles(inputDirectory, @"*.txt"));
```